# Using tokens in code to indicate listings linerange

Tags: listings, lstlisting

I'm aware of how to include specific lines from a file such as:

```
\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=3,firstline=3,lastline=6]{file.c}
```

but I was wondering if there is a way to insert tokens in my code that the listings package can find and determine the linerange from. This way if I add new lines of code to my file the section I want to include wont change.

For example, I would rather do something like

```
\lstinputlisting[token=$--$]{file.c}
```

and have file.c look like:

```
some
code
$--$the
code
I
want$--$
other
code
```

rather than writing:

```
\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=3,firstline=3,lastline=6]{file.c}
```

that way, if file.c changes to:

```
some
code
with
more
code
added
$--$the
code
I
want$--$
other
code
```

it still only displays:

```
the
code
I
want
```

Comment: What do you mean by `tokens`? It would be good if you gave a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you mean. It would be easy to "load" a list of automatically generated line numbers that should be included, but I suspect that this is not what you mean. On the other hand, it would also be easy to have a script look for your "tokens" and throw the associated line numbers into a file that latex could then read, so this might be enough.

Comment: If I could make a MWE I wouldn't have to ask this question, but I've changed the question to include an example of what I want to be able to do